# Replace text inside div

Tags: c#-4.0, replace

I have a lot of html files that I want to add a rel="nofollow" to all the a href tags that are into a specific div.

I think c# code can do it. But how do I relate only partial code..?

Any suggestion? also I didnt realy know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think:

1. Parse the HTML line by line
2. Look for " block start you would need to find the  means look for "/div>".
3. Store all the content between "" into a string
4. check if "href=" is found and how many
5. Now parse this string again to search all  "" and match with "href=" counter
6. #5 will give you an array of "href=" tag based lines
7. Now you can assume every "href=" tag must have ">" at the end of the "

At the last this is what you can do:

```
 string s1 = "<a href=\"mylink\"> this is link </a>";
 string s2 = s1.Insert(s1.IndexOf(">"), " rel=\"nofollow\"");
```

Comment: But how do I find the specific div start and end.. Because there could be a lot of </div> until I reach my specific </div>

Comment: There could be several ways you could do it. You can use ID="your_choice" in specific "Div" look for ID. otherwise, you just need to create an array of all "Div" and search for whatever you are looking for...

Comment: To find the div is not a problem. The problem is to find its closing tag

Comment: I do agree however you need to add some machine learning in your code i.e. search for "/Div>" and "/Div >" and "/ Div >". If your Read RFC all 3 variation could be valid however behavior could be different on each browser due to implementation. You can do the same.

Comment: Best would be start writing the code following above guideline and when you met any problem ask separate question with code snippet and you will get instance help.